# Special Licensing

Tags: licensing

I’m a normal citizen in Ontario Canada. Authorities are failures on my subject. From police to RCMP and in between.
Is it possible to apply for a licence to investigate with similar authorities as a armed police officer temporarily. 
And is there a third party way of solving problems above the court system?

Comment: "above the court system" - God or mediation

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not become a private police officer. You can hold the person and then call the police though. https://www.justice.gc.ca/eng/rp-pr/other-autre/wyntk.html